# Laravel 5 - paginate Eloquent collection

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5

Model:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function trainings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Training');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```php
return view('category', [
    'trainings' => Category::find(1)->trainings->paginate(10)
]);
```

I'm getting `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()` error.

How can I paginate Eloquent Collection in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to call `trainings` as a method:

```
Category::find(1)->trainings()->paginate(10)
//                          ^^
```